# How do I make a uitable in GUIDE of a specific format?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I need to create a MATLAB GUI uitable of the following format:

Environment (Column name)
( Segm ,Arc,Circuit) (pop up menu options)

Location (column name)
(City,country,Highway) (pop up menu options)

Environment is a column name and `Segm,Arc,Circuit` should come as popup menu options; similarly for the Location column name 'City,Country and Highway should come as pop up options)
And also I need to create a checkbox in the third column.

I was creating the code for it but unfortunately it does not form the format wanted above:

```
type_environment ={'Segm' 'Arc' 'Circuit' 'Intersection' 'Round' 'Spline'};
type_Location ={'City' 'Country' 'Highway'};
columnname ={'Environment' , 'Location'};
tabledata =[type_environment type_Location];
columnformat = {'logical', 'logical'};
columneditable =  [false true]; 
handles.Load_data=uitable('Parent',figure,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.5 0.438 0.4913 0.3],'ColumnWidth','auto','Data', tabledata,'ColumnName', columnname,'ColumnFormat', columnformat,'ColumnEditable', columneditable,'RowName',[] ,'BackgroundColor',[.7 .9 .8],'ForegroundColor',[0 0 0]);
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to show how A) the code relates to your problem and B) what your actual problem is with this code? i.e. what doesn't work?

Comment: Is it clearer? The code does not work according to the format wanted of the table .

Answer (score 0):

Three of you variables are incorrectly defined.  You want

```
tabledata =[type_environment(1) type_Location(1)]; % Or whatever you want as the default
columnformat = {type_environment, type_Location};
columneditable =  [true true];
```

You'll also need to add a third column with a logical type.